Ctrl + Mouse Wheel fixed to changing between workspaces in 22.04.5 -- Can't zoom in with Mouse Wheel
An out-of-the box Dell desktop has Ctrl + Mouse Wheel set to default shift among workspaces. No solution I have come across can give me back the ability to use Ctrl + Mouse Wheel to Zoom In and Out, instead. Using dconf-editor, I found that /gnome/eog/view/scroll-wheel-zoom was set to False on Default. I set it to true, but still to no avail.

I have the same issue.
I also tried, without luck, the dconf-editor option.
Ctrl + Mouse Wheel works, for me, if logged in under X11, but not Wayland.
There are however some users reporting success when using Meta+Ctrl+Scroll (Win+Ctrl+Scroll) to zoom on Wayland.
Hopefully a solution is found for this soon!
